# Create a BaseComponent for web components, and refer to component name once

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I have noticed there are a few common/repeated methods I keep reusing in some web components I am working on. When I change the method in one, if I want the improvement in the others, I have to open each one and make the changes to all the other components, which is tedious and error prone. So I am trying to create a `BaseComponent` which the other components inherit from.

The issue is I would like to define the component name, e.g. `wc-thingy` in one place, keep it DRY. However this name is requried in two places:

1. To find the template of the component (I name the id of the template `TEMPLATE_<component_name>`, e.g. `TEMPLATE_wc-thingy`
2. To `customElements.define` it.

Below is my attempt to try accomplish it, but I think the issue is `this.constructor` is not refering to the subclass class instance:

```js
window.BaseComponent = class extends HTMLElement {
    static componentName;

    static define(componentName) {
        this.constructor.componentName = componentName;
        window.customElements.define(this.constructor.componentName, this);
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE_" + this.constructor.componentName);
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        console.log("Contructed", this.constructor.componentName)
    }

    sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
};

(class extends window.BaseComponent {
    sayBi() {
        console.log("K Bi, thxns!");
    }
}).define('wc-thingy')
```

```html
<wc-thingy>thingy here</wc-thingy>
```

Comment: Found this as I was looking for something to use with declarative shadow DOM. I think the situation has improved now that we can declare the shadow upfront, on the server side. That removes the need for template naming. Here are some details about the how's of the declarative shadow DOM https://developer.chrome.com/en/articles/declarative-shadow-dom/ (still needs Firefox shim for the moment, hopefully implemented soon)

Comment: @eduard Thanks for the heads up, looks great in how it handles CSS, but to me a deal breaker is repeating the Template HTML everytime.

Comment: Indeed, repeating that is a bit of problem. I worked around it by including the template on the server as server side template, so I only repeat {{template "wc-tmp" .}}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for creating **your own** `BaseComponent`

-392.176.112 if you now think you are great, and sell it to the world like [the other 60+ BaseClasses](https://webcomponents.dev/blog/all-the-ways-to-make-a-web-component/)

The Web Component name is in `this.nodeName` (uppercase) or `this.localName` (lowercase)

```html
<template id="WC-FOO">foo:<slot></slot></template>
<template id="WC-BAR">bar:<slot></slot></template>

<wc-foo>FOO</wc-foo>
<wc-bar>BAR</wc-bar>

<script>
  class BaseComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const template = () => document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content;
      super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
             .append(template().cloneNode(true));
      console.log("Contructed", this.nodeName , this.localName)
    }
  };
  customElements.define("wc-foo", class extends BaseComponent {});
  customElements.define("wc-bar", class extends BaseComponent {});
</script>
```

Comment: The whole point of what OP is trying to achieve is to move the component registration to a static method on the `BaseElement` class. You've completely ignored that part. It would actually be interesting to learn if static methods on a class have a `this` that is actually bound to the class itself.

Comment: OP writes: *"I would like to define the component name, e.g. wc-thingy in one place"*

Comment: Danny is right, the static method was just a means to an end to try keep it dry. But I do like how @connexo got it to work. You both solved the problem in different ways, I wish I could mark both as correct, thanks very much to both of you!

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman that is funny about trying to share my BaseComponent, don't worry I won't! PS I noticed how you consistantly use `append` vs `appendChild` in your answers, I know you have mentioned in the past that `append` has "more power", but if one is simply appendinga child, its seems like `appendChild` is faster: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/9176/0/js-append-vs-appendchild

Comment: I'm surprised you choose an answer that removes common functionality from your `BaseElement`, like allowing a subclass to simply call `define` to register the element.

Comment: *The Web Component name is in this.nodeName (uppercase) or this.localName (lowercase)* Only if you have an instance, not if all you have is the class, which is why your solution requires passing a magic string to `customElements.define()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the component name as a static accessor property on the *subclass*, not the `BaseElement` class (static properties are not inherited when extending). The property is *read-only* (only has a getter). It makes no sense making it writable as you don't want the `TAG_NAME` to be changeable from the outside.

Returning `this` at the end of your static methods also allows chaining calls, e.g. the call to `define()` is followed by a call to `publish()` (which publishes your class on an object you can pass, default being `window` if you don't pass any) in the example below:

```js
class BaseComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static define() {
    // When called from your subclass, `this` points to that class
    console.log(this.TAG_NAME);
    window.customElements.define(this.TAG_NAME, this);
    return this;
  }
  
  static publish(target = window) {
    target[this.TAG_NAME.replace(/(^\w|-\w)/g, x=>(x[1] ?? x[0]).toUpperCase())] = this;
    return this;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    const template = document.getElementById(
      "TEMPLATE_" + this.constructor.TAG_NAME
    );
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    console.log("Contructed", this.constructor.TAG_NAME);
  }

  sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}

(class extends BaseComponent {
  static get TAG_NAME() {
    return "wc-thingy";
  }

  sayBi() {
    console.log("K Bi, thxns!");
  }
}).define().publish();

console.log('WcThingy' in window)
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE_wc-thingy">
  <h1>Shadow DOM here</h1>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<wc-thingy>thingy here</wc-thingy>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about `this` points to the subclass, and how subclass properties are not inheritted, that is very good info I never knew! And great idea to store the value on the subclass!

Comment: But what is the benefit if the value already is available in ``this.nodeName`` and ``this.localName``? For now I only see **more** boilerplate code. Its a bit potatoes-potatoes [with an english accent]

Comment: The benefit it that you neither need magic strings, you can ask the class for the tag name. Your solution requires magic strings for registering the component. Both `nodeName` and `localName` are only available on **instances**.

Comment: Like I said "potatoes-potatoes", I'd say ``return "wc-thingy";`` is a magical string as well

Comment: A magic string defined in the right place is not a magic string; it's a property of the class that holds a string. It's a magic string if you have to specify it outside of your component code.